# Ruby on Rails and how to render partial using json and jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery, renderpartial

Ruby on Rails newbie whose confused and frustrated :)  I've spent over a day on this and think I've probably just confused myself.

Basically, I'm trying to render a partial in a view.  Here's what I have specifically:
A form with 2 basic fields:  Category and SubCategory.  SubCategory changes depending on what the user selected in Category.  I'm using "JQuery" with the assets pipeline enabled.  This part works:

```
 
    contact_infos.js.coffee

    jQuery(document).ready(->
        $("select#contact_info_category_id").change(->
          id_value_string = $(@).val()
          if id_value_string == ""
            # if the id is empty remove all the sub_selection options from being selectable     and do not do any ajax
            $("select#contact_info_subcategory_id option").remove()
            row = "" + "" + ""
            $(row).appendTo("select#contact_info_subcategory_id")
          else
            # Send the request and update sub category dropdown
            tmp = '/subcategories/for_categoryid/' + id_value_string + '.json'
          $.ajax(
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: tmp,
            timeout: 2000,
            error: (XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error) -> alert "Failed to submit : " + errorTextStatus + " ;" + error,
              success: (data) ->
                # Clear all options from sub category select
                $("select#contact_info_subcategory_id option").remove()
                # put in a empty default line
                row = "" + "" + ""
                $(row).appendTo("select#contact_info_subcategory_id")
                # Fill sub category select
                $.each(data, (i, j) ->
                  row = "" + j.name + ""
                  $(row).appendTo("select#contact_info_subcategory_id")
                )
          )
        )
      )
```

It generates a json response correctly.

When the form loads, in addition to Category and SubCategory, I also have 2 text fields - previous_value and current_value; however, if 
SubCategory == "Full"
then I hide previous_value and current_value and need to insert a partial with new fields.

I'm having no problem hiding previous_value and current_value fields with JQuery works and looks like this (this is inserted into the code above):

```
$("select#contact_info_subcategory_id").change(->
    id_text_string = $("#contact_info_subcategory_id option:selected").text()
    if id_text_string == "Full"
      $('#contact_info_previous_value_id').hide()
      $('#contact_info_current_value_id').hide()
    else
      $('#contact_info_previous_value_id').show()
      $('#contact_info_current_value_id').show()
  )
```

I created a div called "test" in my form where I want to insert the new fields if SubCategory is "Full" and of course, inserting this line into the contact_infos.js.coffee doesn't work:

```
  $('#test').html('<%= escape_javascript render("contact_infos/_full_name_info") %>')
```

as all I get on the page is the string "<%= escape_javascript render("contact_infos/_full_name_info") %>"

I've tried the following but can't get any to work:

1.  creating a new.json.erb file  with the following code:

```
<% self.formats = ["html"] %>
      test = {
        "html":"<%= raw escape_javascript(render :partial =>     'contact_infos/full_name_info',
                    :content_type => 'text/html')} 
                %>"
      }
```

This json file never triggered. My controller has this line:

```
format.json { render json: @contact_info }
```

Is this the best way to do this?  If yes, what can I try next?

2. I saw a posting yesterday (I can't find it now - was on another computer) about creating a javascript variable (I called it fullnamefield) in the application.html.erb layout file as well as adding the js variable to the new.html.erb view, which I did.  I also added this line to the contacts_infos.js.coffee:

```
('#test').html(fullnamefield)
```

and it worked!! EXCEPT that then when I went to any other area of the site, I got an error.

3. As a workaround, I thought about trying to change the json that my jquery produces to a js and then trying to trigger the new.js.erb.  I ran into trouble trying to convert the ajax call.  I could create "json" and also "text" dataTypes but not script (not sure why).

So... any ideas/help?  I've really been searching and I'm frustrated enough that I'm considering just creating all the fields and hidings/showing them as needed from JQuery, which would be so simple to implement but is just wrong.

UPDATE:  Attempt 4 (or is it 40?):

What you wrote got me thinking... I think I'm close but not there yet.

In my _form.html.erb, I added to the Subcategory field data-remote, data-url and data-type:

```
<div class="field">
      <%= f.label :category_id %>
      <br/>
      <%= collection_select(:contact_info, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "--Select a Category--"}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :subcategory_id %>
      <br/>
      <%= collection_select(:contact_info, :subcategory_id, Subcategory.find_all_by_category_id(@contact_info.category_id), :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "--Select a SubCategory"}, "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => "/contact_infos/get_full_fields", "data-type" => :json ) %>
    </div>
```

Then in the contact_infos_controller.rb I added:

```
def get_full_fields
    @full_name = FullName.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

In my routes.rb I modified contact_infos by adding collection do...

```
    resources :contact_infos do
        collection do
          get 'get_full_fields'
        end
      end
```

I created contact_infos\get_full_fields.js.erb:

```
var full_fields_form = $('<%= j(render(:partial => "contact_infos/full_name_info"))%>');
$('#test').html(full_fields_form);
```

Now when I test this in the browser with debugger and change SubCategory to "Full" I can see that it runs correctly (I think) in that I'm getting this back:

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/contact_infos/get_full_fields?contact_info%5Bsubcategory_id%5D=3
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

The "Type" is showing up as "text/javascript."  The Response tab is just showing the javascript code but nothing is happening/triggering.  Even when I place just a

```
alert('hello');
```

in the js file nothing happens.

Any ideas why?

Comment: OK - I finally got it working.  I used solution #4 above with one minor change:

In the contact_infos\_form.html.erb, I had specified the Subcategory field as:

      <%= collection_select(:contact_info, :subcategory_id, Subcategory.find_all_by_category_id(@contact_info.category_id), :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "--Select a SubCategory"}, "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => "/contact_infos/get_full_fields", "data-type" => :json ) %>

Once I changed the "data-type" from :json to :script IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the same way you get subcategory data?  Create a view containing the partial (and corresponding controller action) and call it via ajax when you want to display that content.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response.  I'm afraid I'm going to need more details than that.  I *think* I already tried that (#1 above, where I created a new.json.erb) and I couldn't get the json to trigger. :(